Confusing on ex.9, p.47 Herstein's Topics in Algebra and its answer on Math SE
Question: Topics in Algebra- Hernstein pg-47,Q.9
Suppose that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$  such that whenever $Ha \not=Hb$ then $aH\not=bH$. Prove that $gHg^{-1}\subset H$  for all $g\in G$?
The answer on Math SE:
Using @user29743 hint, let   $a = bh$.  Then $h = b^{-1}a \in H$ means $ba^{-1} = bh^{-1}b^{-1} \in H$, and since $H$ is a subgroup, $(bh^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1} = bhb^{-1} \in H$. Replacing $b$ as $g$ we have: $ ghg^{-1} \in H$.
I have an issue with the above answer. As far as I understand, the exercise says $\forall a,b\in G$ $aH=bH\implies Ha=Hb$ (*). The answer seems to assume that $\forall b\exists a$ $aH=bH$ or consider a certain pair $a,b$ s.t. $aH=bH$ then using $Ha=Hb$ to solve. If, however, there are no $a,b$ s.t. $aH=bH$, (*) is still true. As a result, the aforementioned answer is no longer valid in this case. What have I missed from the problem?
Thanks in advanced!

I think I don't understand what you are trying to ask. For every $b\in G$ there is $a\in G$ such that $bH=aH$ (take $a=b$). Also, under which hypothesis are you taking $a,b$ tot ensure tha $Ha=Hb$?

@Deif I think he may imply that no distinct $a,b$. If we consider $a=b$, the proof just needs $h=e$ s.t. $ah=ha$.
